# Can't initialize the pyttsx3 module

Tags: python

When I am using this in  my program :

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
```

I am getting a error which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\User name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\User name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes38.dll)
```

Please tell me how can I solve this problem.
I searched it on internet and I saw a answer saying that instead of 'sapi5' you can write 'dummy' but after writing dummy my program is not speaking and that's my main motive
Packages:
pyttsx3 - 2.87
python - 3.8.2
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line, it says `No system module 'pywintypes'`. Try installing that with pip or your package manager. It may fix the problem

Comment: No there is no module pywintypes I have tried it. But thanks